# Is there a way of control the wide and precision of a float in the printf() function in C?

Tags: c, floating-point, printf, precision

How can I control the wide (width) and the precision, for example using two integers `int a` and `int b` to which I can assign a value before in the code?

```
printf("%a.bf\n", floatVariable);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbol `*` in place of the numerical value can be used for this:

```
printf("%*.*f\n", a, b, floatVariable);
```

Each `*` in the format string where a numerical value is expected causes an `int` argument to be consumed from the argument list and used as the numerical value.

Note that just like `floatVariable` must be of type `double` or `float` if you pass it to be printed with `%f`, the variables `a` and `b` **must** be of type `int` for this notation to work. If they aren't, you must use:

```
printf("%*.*f\n", (int)a, (int)b, floatVariable);
```

Comment: Why doesn't this have more votes? It's the perfect answer to this question.